# Qual a diferença entre Entidade Associativa e a Tabela intermediária de relacionamentos N para N?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, entidade-relacionamento

Qual a diferença entre **Entidade Associativa** e a **Tabela intermediária de relacionamentos N para N**?
Existe alguma diferença notável na tradução do modelo **ER** para o **modelo relacional**?

No modelo ER as entidades associativas são representadas por um retângulo em volta do relacionamento. E os relacionamentos N pra N não.

Relacionamento N pra N
[image: Relacionamento N pra N]

Entidade Associativa
[image: Entidade Associativa]

Answer (score 5):

A Tabela intermediária de relacionamentos N para N é a tabela gerada no mapeamento conceitual-lógico de cardinalidades N para N. Todo relacionamento N:N gera uma tabela no mapeamento.

A Entidade Associativa é quando o relacionamento com cardinalidade N:N entre duas entidades precisa se relacionar com uma terceira entidade. Nesses casos, esse relacionamento precisaria estar conectado a alguma representação gráfica (ou a uma entidade ou a um relacionamento). Caso seja nas entidades, os vínculos são perdidos e caso seja no relacionamento, a modelagem estaria errada pois não é possível que dois relacionamentos estejam conectados entre si. Para isso, é feito o retângulo em volta do relacionamento. Vejamos um exemplo:

[image: MER Acadêmico]

Se tentarmos ligar a entidade DISCIPLINA na entidade ALUNO, perderíamos a informação de que curso ela faz parte. Se ligarmos no CURSO, perderíamos a informação de qual aluno fez a disciplina. Se ligarmos no relacionamento direto, teríamos um erro de modelagem. Para isso, usa-se uma entidade associativa. No mapeamento conceitual-lógico, a entidade associativa é uma tabela como no relacionamento com cardinalidade N:N, mas a chave primária dela poderá ir para outra tabela como chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 3):

Na entidade associativa, também chamada de agregação, imagine que queira saber se o medicamento que o médico receitou para o paciente em um consulta qualquer necessita de receita (um flag na entidade medicamento). Relacionar a entidade Medicamento como a entidade Médico ou com Paciente não faz sentido, uma vez que a emissão de receita refere-se a consulta realizada. Sendo assim, a entidade Medicamento deve se relacionar a Consulta. Já as tabelas intermediárias geralmente contêm apenas duas colunas que atuam como um link entre as duas tabelas principais, como é o caso entre Engenheiro e Projeto.